# How can I make this div element dissapear

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have this code on my website and this div appears when u successfully post a comment.
Now I want the div element disappear after 3-5 seconds. Here's my code:

```
echo "<div class='granted'><p>Comment posted.</p></div>";

            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                setTimeout(function() {
                $('.granted').fadeOut('fast');
                }, 3000);
            </script>";
```

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Don't use PHP to echo chunks of static HTML and JS. 2. your code seems valid. Did you remember to import JQuery? What do you see in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works perfectly. I think you have missed to link the script library. 
Adding this line before the PHP script does the trick.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work perfectly. You can also use the [`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function:

```
$('.granted').delay(3000).fadeOut('fast');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('.granted').hide();}, 5000); 
});
```

Answer (score -2):

It's not good practice to include HTML tags inside php codes.

```
<div class='granted'><p>Comment posted.</p></div>

<script>
  $(function(){

          setInterval(function(){
               $('.granted').fadeOut(1);
          },5000);


  });
</script>
```

Comment: I think that will start fading immediately and take 5 seconds to do so.  Amir wants the div to wait 5 seconds before fading out.

Comment: @MrVimes Its working in mine .. was in a hurry to submit a answer so that i will edit it after testing the code and modify in few mins .. but u guys were hurry in voting me down .. lol ..